# Java ATM program just prints at ATM.(init)(ATM.java:6) but compiles with no errors (not using any arrays in program)

Tags: java

I'm making an ATM program to learn java using cmd to compile and run it. The program compiles with no errors but when running it only prints `at ATM.(init)(ATM.java:6)`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
public class ATM
{
    Toolbox myToolbox = new Toolbox();
    Integer balance;
    ATM myATM = new ATM();

    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
        ATM myATM = new ATM();
        myATM.go();
        myATM.printBal();
        myATM.mainMenu();
    }

    public void go()
    {
        System.out.println("Welcome to online ATM banking");
        System.out.println("How much do you want in your account?");
        //System.out.println("Enter your number");      
        balance = myToolbox.readIntegerFromCmd();
    }   

    public void printBal()
    {
        System.out.println("****************************************");
        System.out.println(balance);
        System.out.println("****************************************");
    }

    public void mainMenu()
    {
        Integer selected;
        System.out.println("What do you want to do?");
        System.out.println("1 : Withdraw");
        System.out.println("2 : Deposit");
        System.out.println("3 : Inquire");
        System.out.println("4 : Quit");
        System.out.println("Enter your number");
        selected = myToolbox.readIntegerFromCmd();
        //{ if statement for mainMenu options
        if(selected.equals(1))
        {
            myATM.withdraw();
        }
        else if(selected.equals(2))
        {
            myATM.deposit();
        }
        else if(selected.equals(3))
        {
            myATM.inquire();
        }
        else if(selected.equals(4))
        {
            myATM.quit();
        }
        //} if statement end 
    }
    //{ mainMenu methods
    public void withdraw()
    {
        System.out.println("****************************************");
        System.out.println("Withdraw");
        System.out.println("****************************************");
        Integer takeOut;
        System.out.println("How much do you want to withdraw?");
        takeOut= myToolbox.readIntegerFromCmd();
        balance = balance - takeOut;
        myATM.printBal();
        myATM.mainMenu();
    }

    public void deposit()
    {
        System.out.println("****************************************");
        System.out.println("Deposit");
        System.out.println("****************************************");
        Integer putIn;
        System.out.println("How much do you want to deposit?");
        putIn = myToolbox.readIntegerFromCmd();
        balance = balance + putIn;
        myATM.printBal();
        myATM.mainMenu();
    }

    public void inquire()
    {
        System.out.println("****************************************");
        System.out.println("Inquire");
        System.out.println("****************************************");
        //why am I making a method that is already written
        myATM.printBal();
        myATM.mainMenu();
    }

    public void quit()
    {
        System.out.println("****************************************");
        System.out.println("Thanks for using the fail ATM");
        System.out.println("****************************************");
        System.out.println(balance);
        System.out.println("****************************************");
        System.out.println("Goodbye");
        System.out.println("****************************************");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    //}
}
```

Comment: The "at ATM.(init)(ATM.java:6)" looks like a partial stack trace.  Is that the only thing that gets printed in your terminal window?

Comment: Yep it gets printed many times (fills cmd so i cant see how many but doesn't loop endlessly)

Comment: What exactly is on line # **6** in your `ATM.java` file?

Comment: ATM myATM = new ATM(); is 6th on cmd
and i repeated it in main and in the class as it throws up errors "non-static variable myATM cannot be referenced from a static context"

Comment: Ah, (nearly) infinite recursion.  The second assignment in your program is the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the problem is probably line 4 (I think) prior to the main method anyway.

```
ATM myATM = new ATM();
```

this is instanciating an ATM inside every ATM instance and causing an infinite loop of them, eventually a StackOverflowException will be thrown. but it will be a long way down the stack.

replace the corresponding lines with:

```
private static ATM myATM;

public static void main(String[] arg)
{
    myATM = new ATM();
```

Comment: it should be `public static ATM myATM = null`. You can not make a non-static ref from a static method.

Comment: @user1642671 updated because I forgot the static keyword as noted by Ravi thanks that is what I get for not using an IDE to look at the code.

Answer (score 2):

Kind of hard to see if this compiles with your toolbox.
But you could use this instead of myATM and use a while loop instead calling the same method.

```
public class ATM {
    Toolbox myToolbox = new Toolbox();
    Integer balance;

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        ATM myATM = new ATM();
        myATM.go();
        myATM.printBal();
        myATM.mainMenu();
    }

    public void go() {
        System.out.println("Welcome to online ATM banking");
        System.out.println("How much do you want in your account?");
        //System.out.println("Enter your number");      
        balance = myToolbox.readIntegerFromCmd();
    }

    public void printBal() {
        System.out.println("****************************************");
        System.out.println(balance);
        System.out.println("****************************************");
    }

    public void mainMenu() {
        boolean running = true;
        while (running) {
            Integer selected;
            System.out.println("What do you want to do?");
            System.out.println("1 : Withdraw");
            System.out.println("2 : Deposit");
            System.out.println("3 : Inquire");
            System.out.println("4 : Quit");
            System.out.println("Enter your number");
            selected = myToolbox.readIntegerFromCmd();
            //{ if statement for mainMenu options
            if (selected.equals(1)) {
                this.withdraw();
            } else if (selected.equals(2)) {
                this.deposit();
            } else if (selected.equals(3)) {
                this.inquire();
            } else if (selected.equals(4)) {
                this.quit();
                running = false;
            }
        }
        //} if statement end 
    }
    //{ mainMenu methods
    public void withdraw() {
        System.out.println("****************************************");
        System.out.println("Withdraw");
        System.out.println("****************************************");
        Integer takeOut;
        System.out.println("How much do you want to withdraw?");
        takeOut = myToolbox.readIntegerFromCmd();
        balance = balance - takeOut;
        this.printBal();
        //myATM.mainMenu();
    }

    public void deposit() {
        System.out.println("****************************************");
        System.out.println("Deposit");
        System.out.println("****************************************");
        Integer putIn;
        System.out.println("How much do you want to deposit?");
        putIn = myToolbox.readIntegerFromCmd();
        balance = balance + putIn;
        this.printBal();
        //myATM.mainMenu();
    }

    public void inquire() {
        System.out.println("****************************************");
        System.out.println("Inquire");
        System.out.println("****************************************");
        //why am I making a method that is already written
        this.printBal();
        //this.mainMenu();
    }

    public void quit() {
        System.out.println("****************************************");
        System.out.println("Thanks for using the fail ATM");
        System.out.println("****************************************");
        System.out.println(balance);
        System.out.println("****************************************");
        System.out.println("Goodbye");
        System.out.println("****************************************");
    }
    //}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have a separate initialization of:

```
ATM myATM = new ATM();
```

right above the main() method? That seems to be your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The real error here is a *java.lang.StackOverflowError*.

Basically you are having a cycle in your code :

1. You create an instance of a class ATM in your main.
2. The JVM instanciates the atm object of your class in order to create the instance. (3rd variable in your code).
3. The constructor is called again.
4. the JVM tries to create a new instance of ATM and therefore instanciates another instance  variable (GO back to step 2).

There are a few errors in your code. You do not seem to need an ATM object in your class, you can access the ATM instance variables and the methods such as toolbox or balance by using the *this* keyword.

Therefore try to remove the 3rd variable myATM. You do not need it and replace the myATM in your methods (except main) by *this*.